# Using while loop to take all even numbers from a vector and adding 3 to each of them

Tags: r

I have this function in R:

```
is.evenplus3 <- function(x) {
   y <- x[which(x %% 2 == 0)] 
   a <- y + 3
   return(a)
}
```

Which basically takes a numeric vector like a simple sequence, say 2:20, and returns all the even values plus 3.

```
> x <- 2:20
> is.evenplus3(x)
[1]  5  7  9 11 13 15 17 19 21 23
```

And I have basically the same function using a `for` loop:

```
is.even.plus3.for <- function(x) {
   for (i in x) {
     if (i %% 2) {
       next
     }
     print(i + 3)
   }
}
```

which returns the same result but like this:

```
> is.even.plus3.for(x)
[1] 5
[1] 7
[1] 9
[1] 11
[1] 13
[1] 15
[1] 17
[1] 19
[1] 21
[1] 23
```

Two questions:

- I would like to make the second function return the same result but in a single vector, like the first function does. Could not figure it out...
- I would like to make the same function, with the same result as in first function, but using a `while` loop, instead of a `for` loop. I tried but it came out to be an infinite loop...

Comment: @Psidom: it's pretty basic, but it seems like a reasonable self-learning question and the OP has made an effort. To the OP: try (1) setting up a counter `j` that starts from 1 and is only incremented when you get to an odd `i`; (2) allocating a vector `result` of the appropriate length (e.g. use `numeric()`); (3) setting `result[j]` to the desired value, rather than printing

Comment: Yes, it's kind of an exercise to practise loops but got stuck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is the answer, hope you will learn something from it.

a.

```
is.even.plus3.for <- function(x) {
res <- numeric()
for (i in x) {
 if (i %% 2) {
   next
 }
 res <- c(res,(i + 3))
}
 return(res)
}
```

b.

```
is.even.plus3.while <- function(x) {
    i <- 1
    res <- numeric()
    while(i <= length(x) + 1) {
        if (i %% 2) {
            i <- i+1
            next
        }
        res <- c(res,(i + 3))
        i <- i+1
    }
    return(res)
}
```

Comment: (1) It would be more helpful if you tried to explain things to the OP rather than just presenting them with an answer. (2) Building the vector successively by appending (`res <- c(res,...)`) is fine for toy examples but is a bad habit to get into, because it's very time-inefficient in R.

Comment: (1) you probably right. (2) the kength of the needed vector is unknown until the loop ends...

Comment: (2) true. it's a little advanced for this example, but one could set aside a vector longer than expected to be needed and then truncate it ...

Comment: @BenBolker Agreed :)

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
x <- 2:20

# return even values from x. just to be sure everything is working as expected
x[which(x %% 2 == 0 )]
[1]  2  4  6  8 10 12 14 16 18 20

# add 3
x[which(x %% 2 == 0 )] + 3
[1]  5  7  9 11 13 15 17 19 21 23
```

Notice that this works for any arbitrary vector

```
# arbitrary vector
y <- c(1,8,4,2,100,7,9) 

y[which(y %% 2 == 0 )]
[1] 8 4 2 100

y[which(y %% 2 == 0 )] + 3
[1] 11  7  5  103
```

Source for identifying even values: http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/identifying-odd-or-even-number-td2275447.html